# StoreAppLicense status "Inactive license" of UWP app

Tags: uwp

Below is the code for a UWP app to get license info on the user's PC

```
 private static async Task<int> getLicenseState()
    {
        StoreAppLicense license = await appStoreContext.GetAppLicenseAsync();
        //string licenseMode;
         
        if (license.IsActive)
        {
            if (license.IsTrial)
            {
                //licenseMode = "Trial license";
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //licenseMode = "Full license";
                return 1; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //licenseMode = "Inactive license";
            return 2;
        }
         
    }
```

What I confused about is how to process the app when it detects "Inactive license"?

stop the app? or just display some warning info? or trigger a window to ask the user to buy the app?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the current application license invalid, then you can use [StoreContext.RequestPurchaseAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.requestpurchaseasync) to remind users to purchase the application.

```cs
private StoreContext context = null;

public async void PurchaseAddOn(string storeId)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        context = StoreContext.GetDefault();
        // If your app is a desktop app that uses the Desktop Bridge, you
        // may need additional code to configure the StoreContext object.
        // For more info, see https://aka.ms/storecontext-for-desktop.
    }

    workingProgressRing.IsActive = true;
    StorePurchaseResult result = await context.RequestPurchaseAsync(storeId);
    workingProgressRing.IsActive = false;

    // Capture the error message for the operation, if any.
    string extendedError = string.Empty;
    if (result.ExtendedError != null)
    {
        extendedError = result.ExtendedError.Message;
    }

    switch (result.Status)
    {
        case StorePurchaseStatus.AlreadyPurchased:
            textBlock.Text = "The user has already purchased the product.";
            break;

        case StorePurchaseStatus.Succeeded:
            textBlock.Text = "The purchase was successful.";
            break;

        case StorePurchaseStatus.NotPurchased:
            textBlock.Text = "The purchase did not complete. " +
                "The user may have cancelled the purchase. ExtendedError: " + extendedError;
            break;

        case StorePurchaseStatus.NetworkError:
            textBlock.Text = "The purchase was unsuccessful due to a network error. " +
                "ExtendedError: " + extendedError;
            break;

        case StorePurchaseStatus.ServerError:
            textBlock.Text = "The purchase was unsuccessful due to a server error. " +
                "ExtendedError: " + extendedError;
            break;

        default:
            textBlock.Text = "The purchase was unsuccessful due to an unknown error. " +
                "ExtendedError: " + extendedError;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: does 'Inactive license' mean the current application license expires

Comment: Hello, you can use `StoreAppLicense.ExpirationDate` to determine whether the license has expired. I have revised the relevant description in the answer to avoid misunderstanding. According to the description in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense.isactive?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Services_Store_StoreAppLicense_IsActive), when `StoreAppLicense.IsActive` is **False**, it means that the license is invalid and the user may need to purchase the application.

Comment: Can this (`StoreAppLicense.IsActive`) be used to detect sideloaded pirated instances of an app?